# How to display a section in ObjectPageLayout without giving blocks in IconTabBar mode?

Tags: sapui5

I am working on a ObjectPageLayout with the property useIconTabBar:true. I came across a scenario where I need to prepare sections for ObjectPageLayout for the property 'SECTIONS' in my model. I need to prepare the blockcontent only for the selected section and not for all the sections. I can give block aggregation only for the selected section. By doing so, it displays only one section for which I gave block content. How can I display all the sections in the bar without giving block content for that section?

```
      var objectPageLayout = new sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout({
                useIconTabBar: true,
                //showAnchorBar:false,
                showAnchorBarPopover: false,
               // enableLazyLoading: true,
                upperCaseAnchorBar: false,
                selectedSection: selectedSectionId,
                navigate: [oController.onSectionChange, oController]
            });
         objectPageLayout.bindAggregation("sections", oController.modelName   + ">/SECTN", function (sId, oContext) {
                var contextObject = oContext.getObject(), currentTab, preparePanelContent = false;
                currentTab = oController.getQueryParam("tab") || "";

                preparePanelContent = currentTab === "" && _.findIndex(oController.getSections(), contextObject) === 0;
                if (!preparePanelContent) {
                    preparePanelContent = currentTab === contextObject['SECTN'];
                }
                    var objectPageSection = new sap.uxap.ObjectPageSection({
                        id: oController.createId(contextObject['SECTN']),
                        title: contextObject['DESCR'],
                        visible: contextObject['HDSCT'] === ''
                    }).data("id", contextObject['SECTN']);

                   if(preparePanelContent)
                      {
                    //showPanelContent returns my blockcontent. 
                    var subSection = new sap.uxap.ObjectPageSubSection({
                      blocks: oController.sectionRef[contextObject['SECTN']]
                           });
                  objectPageSection.addSubSection(subSection);
                      }
                return objectPageSection;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check lazy loading component.

```
<ObjectPageLayout id="ObjectPageLayout" enableLazyLoading="true" >
```